# apache storm, load balance, json

Tags: apache-storm

I am using Kafka storm, kafka sends/emits json string to storm, in the storm, I want to distribute the load to a couple of workers based on the key/field in the json. How to do that? In my case, it is groupid field in json string.

For example, I have json like that:

```
{groupid: 1234, userid: 145, comments:"I want to distribute all this group 1234  to one worker", size:50,type:"group json"}
{groupid: 1235, userid: 134, comments:"I want to distribute all this group 1234 to another worker", size:90,type:"group json"}
{groupid: 1234, userid: 158, comments:"I want to be sent to same worker as group 1234", size:50,type:"group json"}
```

I try too use following codes:

```
      1.  TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
      2.  builder.setSpout(SPOUTNAME, kafkaSpout, 1);
      3.  builder.setBolt(MYDISTRIBUTEDWORKER, new DistributedBolt()).setFieldsGroup(SPOUTNAME,new Fields("groupid"));  <---???
```

I am wondering how to put arguments in setFieldsGroup method in line 3. Could someone give me a hint?

Juhani

## ==Testing using storm 0.9.4 ============

=============source codes==============

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

import storm.kafka.KafkaSpout;
import storm.kafka.SpoutConfig;
import storm.kafka.StringScheme;
import storm.kafka.ZkHosts;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.LocalCluster;
import backtype.storm.spout.SchemeAsMultiScheme;
import backtype.storm.task.OutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichBolt;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Tuple;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;


public class KafkaBoltMain {
   private static final String SPOUTNAME="TopicSpout"; 
   private static final String ANALYSISBOLT = "AnalysisWorker";
   private static final String CLIENTID = "Storm";
   private static final String TOPOLOGYNAME = "LocalTopology";


   private static class AppAnalysisBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
       private static final long serialVersionUID = -6885792881303198646L;
        private OutputCollector _collector;
       private long groupid=-1L;
       private String log="test";

       public void prepare(Map conf, TopologyContext context, OutputCollector collector) {
           _collector = collector;
       }

       public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
           List<Object> objs = tuple.getValues();
           int i=0;
           for(Object obj:objs){
               System.out.println(""+i+"th object's value is:"+obj.toString());
               i++;
           }

//         _collector.emit(new Values(groupid,log));
           _collector.ack(tuple);
       }

        public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
            declarer.declare(new Fields("groupid","log"));
        }
   } 

   public static void main(String[] args){
       String zookeepers = null;
       String topicName = null;
       if(args.length == 2 ){
           zookeepers = args[0];
           topicName = args[1];
        }else if(args.length == 1 && args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("help")){ 
           System.out.println("xxxx");
           System.exit(0);
        }
       else{
           System.out.println("You need to have two arguments: kafka zookeeper:port and topic name");
           System.out.println("xxxx");
           System.exit(-1);
        }       

        SpoutConfig spoutConfig = new SpoutConfig(new ZkHosts(zookeepers),
                topicName,
                "",// zookeeper root path for offset storing
                CLIENTID);
        spoutConfig.scheme = new SchemeAsMultiScheme(new StringScheme());
        KafkaSpout kafkaSpout = new KafkaSpout(spoutConfig);

        TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
        builder.setSpout(SPOUTNAME, kafkaSpout, 1);
        builder.setBolt(ANALYSISBOLT, new AppAnalysisBolt(),2)
            .fieldsGrouping(SPOUTNAME,new Fields("groupid"));

        //Configuration
        Config conf = new Config();
        conf.setDebug(false);
        //Topology run
        conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING, 1);
        LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
        cluster.submitTopology(TOPOLOGYNAME, conf, builder.createTopology());
    }
}
```

==================================================
when I start to submit topology(local cluster), it
gives following error:

```
11658 [SyncThread:0] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.ZooKeeperServer - Established session 0x14d097d338c0009 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /127.0.0.1:34656
11658 [main-SendThread(localhost:2000)] INFO  org.apache.storm.zookeeper.ClientCnxn - Session establishment complete on server localhost/127.0.0.1:2000, sessionid = 0x14d097d338c0009, negotiated timeout = 20000
11659 [main-EventThread] INFO  org.apache.storm.curator.framework.state.ConnectionStateManager - State change: CONNECTED
12670 [main] INFO  backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor - Starting supervisor with id ccc57de0-29ff-4cb4-89de-fea1ea9b6e28 at host storm-VirtualBox
12794 [main] WARN  backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus - Topology submission exception. (topology name='LocalTopology') #<InvalidTopologyException InvalidTopologyException(msg:Component: [AnalysisWorker] subscribes from stream: [default] of component [TopicSpout] with non-existent fields: #{"groupid"})>
12800 [main] ERROR org.apache.storm.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory - Thread Thread[main,5,main] died
backtype.storm.generated.InvalidTopologyException: null
        at backtype.storm.daemon.common$validate_structure_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:178) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.common$system_topology_BANG_.invoke(common.clj:307) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__4290$exec_fn__1754__auto__$reify__4303.submitTopologyWithOpts(nimbus.clj:948) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.daemon.nimbus$fn__4290$exec_fn__1754__auto__$reify__4303.submitTopology(nimbus.clj:966) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeMatchingMethod(Reflector.java:93) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at clojure.lang.Reflector.invokeInstanceMethod(Reflector.java:28) ~[clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
        at backtype.storm.testing$submit_local_topology.invoke(testing.clj:264) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.LocalCluster$_submitTopology.invoke(LocalCluster.clj:43) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at backtype.storm.LocalCluster.submitTopology(Unknown Source) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
        at com.callstats.stream.analyzer.KafkaBoltMain.main(KafkaBoltMain.java:94) ~[StreamAnalyzer-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:na]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which version of Storm you are using, as of 0.9.4, your requirement can be implemented as follows.

```
builder.setBolt(MYDISTRIBUTEDWORKER, new DistributedBolt()).fieldsGrouping(SPOUTNAME, new Fields("groupid"));
```

In prepare method of DistributedBolt,

```
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(new Fields("groupid", "log"));
}
```

Somewhere in execute method of it, you will call

```
collector.emit(new Values(groupid, log));
```

then tuples which have same groupid will be delivered to same instance of next bolt.

Comment: That's very helpful information, we are at this moment using storm0.9.3. Thank you for the tip, I will verify it immediately.

Comment: I am using now 0.9.4 and paste source code. Could you please give me more hints? Shall I rmr the zookeeper node?

Comment: Your error has nothing to do with zookeeper. You try to link analysis bolt directly with kafka spout but kafka spout only emits entire message, no groupid field is decalred to be emitted. I think you need one more bolt that reads from kafka spout and generates groupid. And then your analysis bolt should be linked to that.